How to correctly exclude babel plugin
I have .babelrc.js set up like this:
const { join, resolve } = require('path');
const root = resolve(join(__dirname, '..', '..'));

module.exports = {
  presets: [
    [
      require.resolve('@babel/preset-env'),
    ],
  ],
  plugins: [ ... ],
};

I want to exclude @babel/plugin-transform-classes, so I did:
module.exports = {
  presets: [
    [
      require.resolve('@babel/preset-env'),
      { exclude: [ require.resolve("@babel/plugin-transform-classes") ] },
    ],
  ],
  plugins: [ ... ],
};

Then i get error: Error: Your application tried to access @babel/plugin-transform-classes, but it isn't declared in your dependencies; this makes the require call ambiguous and unsound.
I tried removing the require.resolve:
module.exports = {
  presets: [
    [
      require.resolve('@babel/preset-env'),
      { exclude: [ "@babel/plugin-transform-classes" ] },
    ],
  ],
  plugins: [ ... ],
};

Then i get another error: ConfigError: .presets[0][2] must be a string, or undefined
So my question is, what is the correct way to exclude @babel/plugin-transform-classes?
